# onClick() method for a button is not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I am working on uploading videos to firebase, As the first step is to select the video. I am trying to get the video from the storage using the below code. Using the following code, I cannot perform the operation of getting the video from the gallery.

This is how I have initialized my variables

```
        browse = findViewById(R.id.reelupload);//browse button
        upload = findViewById(R.id.reelbrowse);//upload button
        reel = findViewById(R.id.reel);//video view

        mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        reel.setMediaController(mediaController);
```

Below is the code for the onClick method of the browse button

```
browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Dexter.withContext(getApplicationContext())
                        .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {

                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setType("video/*");
                                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                                    permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                            }
                        }).check();
            }
        });


 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            uri = data.getData();
            reel.setVideoURI(uri);
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following statements in the logcat when I click on the browse button

```
2022-06-17 23:14:51.972 1277-1277/com.example.proshare I/ViewRootImpl@2c13be8[reelupload]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
2022-06-17 23:14:51.973 1277-1277/com.example.proshare I/MSHandlerLifeCycle: isMultiSplitHandlerRequested: windowingMode=1 isFullscreen=true isPopOver=false isHidden=false skipActivityType=false isHandlerType=true this: DecorView@2a635e6[reelupload]
2022-06-17 23:14:52.040 1277-1277/com.example.proshare I/ViewRootImpl@2c13be8[reelupload]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
2022-06-17 23:14:52.041 1277-1277/com.example.proshare I/MSHandlerLifeCycle: isMultiSplitHandlerRequested: windowingMode=1 isFullscreen=true isPopOver=false isHidden=false skipActivityType=false isHandlerType=true this: DecorView@2a635e6[reelupload]
2022-06-17 23:14:52.153 1277-1290/com.example.proshare I/xample.proshar: Compiler allocated 4546KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
```

Comment: Couldn't help but notice these seems backwards: `browse = findViewById(R.id.reelupload);//browse button` and 
       `upload = findViewById(R.id.reelbrowse);//upload button`  - i.e. you get the id for the upload button but assign it to browse and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I think Your ids for buttons are mismatched